# Jquery insertAfter() correct syntax for the selectors

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a `div`

```html
<div id="imgDIV"><h4>My Debug DIV</h4></div>
```

and I want insert a debug message at the top of the `div` but after the first `h4`, this way I get my latest messages at the top.

```
$('My Debug Messages').insertAfter(the first `h4` of the DIV);
```

but can not get the syntax right to refer to the `h4`.

I have given the `h4` an ID which works, but would like to know the correct syntax for specifying the first `h4` in a `div`.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector to use is:

```
.insertAfter('#imgDIV h4:first-child')
```

If you want to insert a string of plain text, you can't `$()` the text alone as jQuery will treat it like a selector; you'll need to wrap the text in an HTML element and then append that. For example, a `p`:

```
$('<p>My Debug Messages</p>').insertAfter('#imgDIV h4:first-child')
```

Which results in:

```html
<div id="imgDIV"><h4>My Debug DIV</h4><p>My Debug Messages</p></div>
```

Comment: Or, if you prefer chaining over strings, `.insertAfter('#imgDIV h4').first()`.

Comment: Many thanks everyone.   I am learning yet more subtleties, to Jquery and selectors.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
$( '#imgDIV' ).children( 'h4:first' ).after( 'Your message' );
```

Comment: @Esailija Huh? I had no idea I'm using them `:)`

Comment: Heh, I just meant you do `$( '#imgDIV' )` instead of `$('#imgDIV')` :P as explained [here](http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_Core_Style_Guidelines#Spacing)